# Como puedo poner solo el año anterior, sin día, mes y hora C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

`@DateTime.Now.Year` obtengo el año actual.

Quiero obtener el año anterior, pero cuando pongo `@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)`
pone día, mes, año y hora.
Solo necesito que cambie el año.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy");
```